# Different response on Console and infoView in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have to show the response with same order as I have received from my backend team.

But the response sequence is getting changed on extracting the values from Dictionary and array.

Please check the attached screenshot and suggest .

[image]

On extracting , I am getting **7703** but I need **5599** for showing the same position as in my website and in my application

Comment: Dictionary don't have any order

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is not an ordered collection. You should create custom model class and use array of models.

You can use famous third party https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel
 for mapping json to array of models.

Or you can sort dictionary keys (dict.allKeys) or values (dict.allValues)